# How to enlarge the hover area of a QGraphicsItem

Tags: qt, hover, qgraphicsitem

I have a QGraphicsScene with rather small point markers. I would like to enlarge the area of these markers to make dragging easier. The marker is a cross, +/- 2 pixels from the origin. I have reimplemented

```
QGraphicsItem::contains(const QPointF & point ) const
{
  return QRectF(-10,-10,20,20);
}
```

and

```
void hoverEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent* event)
{
  setPen(QPen(Qt::red));
  update();
}
```

but the marker only turns red when it is directly hit by the cursor (and even that is a bit picky). How can I enlarge the "hover area"?

Comment: QGraphicsItem::contains() needs to return a bool. You are returning a QRectF.

Comment: I have no clue why I'm doing that...

Comment: Also, it turns out that contains() is not called after correcting the signature. Even reimplementing boundingRect() doesn't help.

Comment: Usually those things are handled via the bounding rect or the shape function, try overloading those

Comment: Overloading shape() finally changed the behavior. I couldn't find anythting specific about this in the documentation - does it mention which method is used for hover events?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the short comment:
Usually those things are handled via the bounding rect or the shape function, try overloading those. Take a look into the qt help of QGraphicsItem under shape ([https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsitem.html#shape](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qgraphicsitem.html#shape)):

> Returns the shape of this item as a QPainterPath in local coordinates.
> The shape is used for many things, including collision detection, hit
> tests, and for the QGraphicsScene::items() functions.
>
> The default implementation calls boundingRect() to return a simple
> rectangular shape, but subclasses can reimplement this function to
> return a more accurate shape for non-rectangular items. For example, a
> round item may choose to return an elliptic shape for better collision
> detection. For example:
>
> ```cpp
> QPainterPath RoundItem::shape() const {
>     QPainterPath path;
>     path.addEllipse(boundingRect());
>     return path; }
> ```
>
> The outline of a shape can vary depending on the width and style of
> the pen used when drawing. If you want to include this outline in the
> item's shape, you can create a shape from the stroke using
> QPainterPathStroker.
>
> This function is called by the default implementations of contains()
> and collidesWithPath().

So what basically happens is that all functions that want to access the "Zone" which is associated with an item, call shape and then do e.g. a containment or collision detection with the resulting painterpath.
Thus if you have small items you should enlargen the shape zone.
Let's for instance consider a line that is your target, than your shape implementation could look like the following:

```
QPainterPath Segment::shape() const{
  QLineF temp(qLineF(scaled(Plotable::cScaleFactor)));
  QPolygonF poly;
  temp.translate(0,pen.widthF()/2.0);
  poly.push_back(temp.p1());
  poly.push_back(temp.p2());
  temp.translate(0,-pen.widthF());
  poly.push_back(temp.p2());
  poly.push_back(temp.p1());
  QPainterPath path;
  path.addPolygon(poly);
  return path;
}
```

Pen is a member of the segment, and I use its width to enlarge the shape zone.  But you can take anything else as well that has a good relation to the actual dimension of your object.

Comment: It was not clear to me which of QGraphicsItem's methods is called to determine the item's "zone". From what the documentation says, it could be contains(), boundingBox() or shape(). However, your answer is quite helpful, but it was your comment to my question that made the difference.

Comment: Glad I could be of help. Just to clarify: Shape usually calls bounding box if it is not overloaded to do sth. else and shap itself is used by all kinds of functions that want to get a notion of an items dimensions (I agree the documentation is quite poor on that)

Comment: Besides: If you find a comment or an answer helpful, you should upvote it, if it is complete, accept it. Not only as rep reward but mainly to indicate to other users that it helped you with your question and thus might help them as well

Comment: I know, but forgot - thanks for the reminder. Please consider adding the information you gave in your first comment (which I upvoted as well) to your answer.